# Mule 4.1.2 custom connector error

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have created custom connector project using below command,                  "mvn org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-archetype-maven-plugin:generate" in Mule 4. But when i open this project in anypoint studio 7.1.2 it gives below error ('The import org.mule.runtime cannot be resolved') in all of defaultly created java.class files. I have updated the pom file dependencies also, but still issue persists.

Help me to resolve this error, thanks in advance

Thanks,
Videesh.

Answer (score 0):

Studio 7 (including the at this time last release 7.2.2) doesn't support Mule SDK projects. You can use any other IDE that supports generic Maven projects.